# Atibtmon.exe runtime error

Tags: runtime-error

I updated to Windows 10 and every time I disconnect the power cord or don't have power cord on it has a atibtmon.exe runtime error I don't have vari bright selection in amd control center so what do I do?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with the older 43XX  ATI/AMD GPU running on Windows 10 64 bit.  The Catalyst package for Windows 8 no longer provides an option for disabling the 32 bit ATI brightness monitor.  Some solutions on the Internet tell you to maximise the brightness in power settings for the display when on battery power, but that is a sloppy solution.
My solution is quite simple, rename or delete the offending file atibtmon.exe located in C:\Windows\System32.  Everything still runs fine, and the screen brightness levels still change according to your settings. It is not an essential executable. 
Another way is to delete the location entry for this executable in your registry, but why bother when this simple solution works?